# Compare one level vs the others in regression

Tags: regression, categorical-data, biostatistics, contrasts, observational-study

We have a set of exclusive mutations on a set of genes. We would like to estimate the influence of such mutations on a certain syndrome.
Our main problem is how to model the comparison between mutations.

I would like to have your opinion on different ways to model this problem:

- Perform a regression for each mutation in which the predictor is dichotomized as having or not having the mutation. The pro is that I can assess the effect of each single mutation, the cons is the multiplication of analysis.
- Perform a multiple regression in which each yes/no mutation variable is used as covariate. Pro: one analysis. Cons: How do you interpret the adjustment? What is the intercept, considering that the mutations are mutually exclusive?
- Perform a regression with a "mutation" predictor whose contrast allows to compare each level against the average of the others. Pro: very clean and easy to interpret. Cons: I don't know how to implement such contrast in R.

Comment: If the mutations are mutually exclusive, you can define a single column with the mutation type, perhaps a factor with levels `"none", "mutation A", "mutation B", ...`. Then you can include that factor as a predictor. With no mutation as the base level, the default contrasts will correspond to your first bullet but with a single regression.

Comment: The problem is indeed that there is no natural baseline. Each subject has only one mutation. No cases with more than one or zero.

Comment: Any hints yet? It's quite important to us!

Comment: `the cons is the multiplication of analysis` Isn't this why approaches like Benjamini-Hochberg exist?

Comment: I don't know this approach